# Error in search code of php

Tags: php

I want to search my database named phpsearch and column college and 
I am using an explode function to separate the terms with spacing and not commas.
I have a doubt regarding the i term as the error says i is not defined but I though php is a language where you don not have to specify datatypes not declare variable

the code is

```
<?php 
    $k = $_GET['k'];
    $terms = explode(" ",$k);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM colsearch WHERE ";
    foreach ($terms as $each)
    {
        $i++;
        if($i == 1)
        $query .= "college LIKE '%$each%' ";
        else
        $query .= "OR college LIKE '%$each%'";
    }

    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("phpsearch");
    $query = mysql_query($query);
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if($numrows>0){
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
        $id = $row ['id'];
        $college = $row ['college'];
        $govpriv = $row ['govpriv'];
        $description = $row ['description'];
    $departments = $row ['departments'];
        $fees = $row ['fees'];
        $location = $row ['location'];
        $facilities = $row ['facilities'];
        $fests = $row ['fests'];
        $placements = $row ['placements'];
        $link = $row ['link'];

        echo "<h2><a href = '$link'>$college</a></h2>$description<br/><br/>";
    } else {
        echo "No results found for $k";
    }
    mysql_close();
?>
```

What is the error? I tried all possible ways.

Comment: Whoa, this code is ALL the way open for MySQL injection attacks. Always use functions like mysql_real_escape_string when accepting user input as query variables.

Comment: $i is not given a intial value and u are trying to increment it.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to declare `$i = 0;` before the loop if you intend to use the `++` operator in the loop.

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($terms as $each)
{
  $i++;
  if($i == 1)
    $query .= "college LIKE '%$each%' ";
  else
    $query .= "OR college LIKE '%$each%'";
}
```

**Side note**
 - Apart from the error with `$i`, you should read up on SQL-injections, and how to avoid them [using mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Answer (score 1):

the fact that $i is not defined is a notice, not an error (you should declare it before the loop)

the bigger problems here would be:

- you have no security
- you have no error handling
- you do not indent your code
- the variables are poorly named
- your should include the values you assign from the $row array in a block (enclose all of them between brackets) even if in this case you are using only one of the possible results, it's ok to get used to work like that

Comment: You're not answering the OP's question

Comment: @Anzeo: i figured that part was already obvious (as it is mentioned by all the other guys) and I only mentioned it at the beginning ("the fact that $i is not defined is a notice")

Answer (score 0):

you have to initialize $i before using it if you want to use the ++ operator:

```
            $k = $_GET['k'];
            $terms = explode(" ",$k);
            $query = "SELECT * FROM colsearch WHERE ";

            $i = 0; //initialize variable here
            foreach ($terms as $each)
            {
                $i++;
                if($i == 1)
                $query .= "college LIKE '%$each%' ";
                else
                $query .= "OR college LIKE '%$each%'";
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare i is a variable, however you are correct PHP does not require you to specify the type of $i

so add a line declaring $i to your code, like:

```
$i = 0
foreach ($terms as $each)
{
    $i++;
    if($i == 1)
      $query .= "college LIKE '%$each%' ";
    else
      $query .= "OR college LIKE '%$each%'";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way:

```
$k = $_GET['k'];
$terms = implode('|',$k);     
$query = "SELECT * FROM colsearch WHERE college REGEXP '$terms'";
```

MySQL regexp man page : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html